# Java HashSet is allowing dupes; problem with comparable?

Tags: java, set, comparable

I've got a class, "Accumulator", that implements the Comparable compareTo method, and I'm trying to put these objects into a HashSet.

When I add() to the HashSet, I don't see any activity in my compareTo method in the debugger, regardless of where I set my breakpoints.  Additionally, when I'm done with the add()s, I see several duplicates within the Set.

What am I screwing up, here; why is it not Comparing, and therefore, allowing the dupes?

Thanks,
IVR Avenger

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What am I screwing up, here?

HashSet is based on `hashCode()`, not on `compareTo()`. You may be confusing it with `TreeSet`. In both cases, be sure to also implement `equals()` in a manner that is consistent with the other method.

Answer (score 11):

You need to correctly implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

You must override `hashCode` and return a number based on the values in your class such that any two equal objects have the same hashcode.

Comment: without equals it would be totally invalid.

Answer (score 6):

HashSet uses the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods to prevent duplicates from being added.  First, it gets the hash code of the object you want to add.  Then, it finds the corresponding **bucket** for that hash code and iterates through each object in that bucket, using the `equals()` method to see if any identical objects already exist in the set.

Your debugger is not breaking on `compareTo()` because it is never used with `HashSet`!

The rules are:

1. If two objects are equal, then their hash codes
   *must* be equal.
2. But if two objects' hash codes
   are equal, then this *doesn't* mean
   the objects are equal! It could be
   that the two objects just happen to have the same hash.

Answer (score 2):

When hashCode return different values for 2 objects, then equal is not used. Btw, compareTo has nothing to do with hashing collections :) but sorted collections

Answer (score 2):

Your objects are `Comparable`, and probably you've implemented `equals()` too, but `HashSets` deal with object hashes, and odds are you haven't implemented `hashCode()` (or your implementation of `hashCode()` doesn't return the same hash for two objects that are `(a.equals(b) == true)`.

Answer (score 2):

One thing which people tends to ignore which result in a huge mistake.
While defining equals method always take the parameter as object class and then conver the object to your desired class.
For eg

```
   public bolean equals(Object aSong){
     if(!(aSoneg instanceof Song)){
       return false;
     }
     Song s=(Song) aSong;
     return getTitle().equals(s.getTitle());
   }
```

If u pass write Song aSong instead of Object aSong your equals method will never get called.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

HashSet uses hashCode and equals. TreeSet uses the Comparable interface. Note: if you decide to override either hashcode or equals, you should always override the other.

Comment: You only need to override hashCode if equals is overridden (definition is equality has changed). The other way around is not necessarily true. It's perfectly legal to change hashCode to return 1 and leave equals alone.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you create an object of class **Accumulator** it takes new space in **JVM** and returns unique **hashCode** every time you add an object in **hashSet**. It does not depends upon the value of the object because you have not overridden **hashCode()** method hence it will call **Object** class **hashCode()** method which will return unique hashCode with every object created in your program.

Solution:

Override **hashCode()** and **equals()** method and apply your logic depending upon the properties of your class. Be sure to read equals and hashcode contract

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html

Comment: the provided link is very helpful and for bininer people like me it is very useful.