# Eliminate duplicate from List containing objects using collection in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I have created a student class with details studentId, StudentName and studentSemester. Then added a constructor to create new students. in the main method i have given the below.

```
Student s1 = new Student(101, "Ron", 1);
    Student s2 = new Student(102, "Angela", 9);
    Student s3 = new Student(103, "Hazel", 5);
    Student s4 = new Student(104, "David", 3);
    Student s5 = new Student(104, "Alan", 4);
    Student s6 = new Student(103, "Hazel", 5);
    Student s7 = new Student(101, "Ron", 1);
    List<Student> reEvaluationDetails = new ArrayList<Student>();
    reEvaluationDetails.add(s1);
    reEvaluationDetails.add(s2);
    reEvaluationDetails.add(s3);
    reEvaluationDetails.add(s4);
    reEvaluationDetails.add(s5);
    reEvaluationDetails.add(s6);
    reEvaluationDetails.add(s7);
```

from the list, i have to eliminate duplicates by using another collection. I have tried adding the elements to a LinkedHashset but it doesnt remove the duplicates. Could you please suggest any solutions.

Comment: override equals and hasCode method in student class. it will work for hashset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HashSet contains duplicate entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238182/hashset-contains-duplicate-entries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods in `Strudent` and the use `Set`,

```
class Student {
    public String name;
    public int id;
    public int semester;

    public Student(int id, String name, int semester) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.semester = semester;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Student student = (Student) o;
        return id == student.id &&
                semester == student.semester &&
                Objects.equals(name, student.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, id, semester);
    }
}
```

Then use `Set`,

```
 LinkedHashSet<Student> students = new LinkedHashSet<>(reEvaluationDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set.

A Set is  a Collection that, unlike List, does not allow duplicates.

```
Set<Student> reEvaluationDetails = new HashSet<Student>();
reEvaluationDetails.add(s1);
reEvaluationDetails.add(s2);
reEvaluationDetails.add(s3);
reEvaluationDetails.add(s4);
reEvaluationDetails.add(s5);
reEvaluationDetails.add(s6);
reEvaluationDetails.add(s7);
```

And override the equals and hashcode:

```
class Student {
    int id;
    String name;
    int whatever;

    Student(int id, String name, int whatever) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.whatever = whatever;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Student student = (Student) o;
        return id == student.id &&
                whatever == student.whatever &&
                Objects.equals(name, student.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, whatever);
    }
}
```

When you check what's in the Set you'll see that there are no duplicates.

It's the most efficient way of doing it.

You can check it running [here](http://tpcg.io/pawaTPTk).

Comment: I have tried this but it is also returning duplicates while priding the set.

Comment: Because you have to also override its equals and hashcode. Check the update and the running link

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using distinct [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--)

reEvaluationDetails .stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()).

The equals() method of you student class should be overriden to detect equality between Student object

Answer (score 0):

converting the ArrayList to a HashSet effectively removes duplicates, if you need to preserve insertion order you can also use this

```
Set<String> reEvaluationDetails = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);

reEvaluationDetails.add(s1);
reEvaluationDetails.add(s2);
reEvaluationDetails.add(s3);
reEvaluationDetails.add(s4);
reEvaluationDetails.add(s5);
reEvaluationDetails.add(s6);
reEvaluationDetails.add(s7);
```