# Why are my duplicate entries not filtered out with HashSet, but with TreeSet they are?

Tags: java, collections, hashset, treeset

I have tried a little bit here. But I don't understand why TreeSet can filter out the duplicate entries here, but HashSet can't.

```
public class DataClass implements Comparable<DataClass> {
    private final String data;

    public DataClass(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null || other.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
        DataClass dc = (DataClass) other;
        return this.data.length() == dc.data.length();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DataClass dc) {
        return Integer.compare(this.data.length(), dc.data.length());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Here is my main Method:

```
DataClass[] data = new DataClass[4];
        data[0] = new DataClass("Hans");
        data[1] = new DataClass("Tom");
        data[2] = new DataClass("Fred");
        data[3] = new DataClass("Sia");

    
        System.out.println();
        TreeSet<DataClass> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
        for (DataClass dc : data) treeSet.add(dc);
        for (DataClass dc : treeSet)
            System.out.print(dc+" ");

        System.out.println();
        HashSet<DataClass> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (DataClass dc : data)
            hashSet.add(dc);
        for (DataClass dc : hashSet)
            System.out.print(dc+" ");
```

The ouput is:

```
Tom Hans 
Hans Tom Fred Sia
```

Doesn't HashSet pay attention to equals() method? I haven't found anything in the documentation now either. Did I miss something?

Comment: Or use just `data.length()` as an `int` value is already sufficient as its own hash code.

Comment: However, on the official documentation I don't see how HashSet does the comparisons ([See Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)). Where can I get this information in the future that equals() and hashCode() must be the same for this class?

Comment: look at the .add() function in the documentation, the link is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add-E-

Comment: Thank you very much. However, nothing says that HashSet still involves the hashCode() function.

Comment: Since you have overridden `equals`, you should have looked at [the contract of equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) to see, how to do it correctly. And it says: “*Note that it is generally necessary to override the `hashCode` method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the `hashCode` method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.*”

Answer (score 7):

You need to override the `hashCode()` method in order for the `HashSet` to not contain duplicates, since the `HashSet` only checks for equality if there are collisions. However, `TreeSet` doesn't require `hashCode()` to be overridden. See: [HashSet contains duplicate entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238182/hashset-contains-duplicate-entries)

Comment: However, on the official documentation I don't see how HashSet does the comparisons ([See Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)). Where can I get this information in the future that equals() and hashCode() must be the same for this class?

Comment: Look at the .add() function in the documentation, the link is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add-E-

Answer (score 2):

`HasSet` is a hashing based data structure so to consider two object being same, you need to implement `hashCode` and `equals` method. If two object return same values for these methods they are considered same.

`TreeSet` uses `compareTo` so you are good.

Read about hashCode and equals contract.

Answer (score 1):

`TreeSet` uses `compareTo` method to find data whereas `HashSet` uses `hashCode` and `equals` method.

Documentation of `HashSet` says -

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance).

And the documentation of `HashMap` says -

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets

That means, `hashCode` method will be used to locate the bucket and `equals` method will be used to find exact match.

In your case as you are using TreeMap and you have provided `compareTo` method -

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(DataClass dc) {
        return Integer.compare(this.data.length(), dc.data.length());
    }
```

`TreeSet` is comparing objects using it's length but for `HashSet` all the objects are different as you have not overridden `hashCode` and `equals` methods.

Comment: However, on the official documentation I don't see how HashSet does the comparisons ([See Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)). Where can I get this information in the future that equals() and hashCode() must be the same for this class?